# Why is this vote number written in words on one of these answers, and also for the question?

Tags: support, voting

[This question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9724/why-was-a-k-gastev-purged-in-1939) on History SE has the question votes and *some* of the answer votes written out in letters:

[image]

I assume this a bug of some sort (?), and I cannot find any other questions displaying this (although my search was admittedly far from exhaustive as there are over 13,000 questions on History SE).

Note: the 'bug' may seem to be related to my voting but if you check the link you'll see this not the case.

Something else odd: my badges total display on the same page (and only on this page):

[image]

Comment: Note for me that the "eight" shows as the normal "8".

Comment: No repro from me. What happens if you log out and view the same page? Or view it from incognito mode? Can you try disabling extensions and see if it goes away? I once saw  that happen when I used Chrome's translate option to translate the Japanese version of stack overflow. Did you perhaps translate to some language and then translate back to English?

Comment: Oh I just noticed that there is Russian on that page. Did you use Chrome's translate option to translate the Russian into English? I noticed that feature is persistent so once you turn on translations it will keep translating. If so, there should be an option to disable translating near the address bar. **Edit:** that appears to be the case because the quoted section for the answer with a score of 7 is in Russian for me but in your screenshot it's English.

Comment: Blame Google, not SE.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Thanks, useful observations. It doesn't appear if I'm not logged in when using my mobile device Yes, the page does translate automatically from Russian - but why does this happen with some numbers but not others? I'm more curious than concerned about this (as long as it's not an indication that something more might be wrong).

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward Yes, seems you are right.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate of: [Vietnamese to English translation issue](/q/361994/289905), [Google Translate, languages, and numbers oh my!](/q/272536/289905).